# What is the full path of this script? ECMAScript equivalent to %~f0

Tags: photoshop-script, ecmascript-3

This got me stumped.

In a (Windows) batch file I can file the name of the file and path of said batch file with:

```
SET thisfile=%~f0
ECHO thisfile
```

`C:\Users\GwenStefani>C:\projects\scripts\this_file.bat`

However, I want to do this is Photoshop. I can find the name of the current document with:

```
var myPath = app.activeDocument.path;
var myDoc = myPath + "/" + app.activeDocument.name;
alert(myDoc);
```

...But the file path (and name) of the script that's just be called - I'm all out of ideas.
Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

After a let more digging, I found what you after, recorded here for my future self:

```
var myScript = $.fileName;
alert(myScript);
```

`/c/somefolder/gwen/stefani/myscript.jsx`